# Wordpress using differet domain

Tags: wordpress, apache

Hello I have the following environment:

Domain A (redirect to domain B) Apache server

Domain B (separate web server where is installed Wordpress) Apache server

So if I digit the url of domain A I see the homepage of Wordpress site.

My problem is that if I click any link in the website I will be redirected to the Domain B because the site use the permalink of the wordpress installation.

Is there any chance to use the domain A name as base URL?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry - this question is not clear. Did you migrate the site? Or are you making a copy? Are those domains different - or maybe subdomains. Maybe try to share those domains if they are live. Hard to help if it's not clear what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed wordpress under the domain:

[www.domain-a.com](http://www.domain-a.com)

I have another domain:

[www.domain-b.com](http://www.domain-b.com)

that is configured to point to every single page of domain-a

so if I point to URL: www.domain-b/example-page I can see correctly the wordpress page. My problem is that if I click on every link inside this page the permalink is cofigured for domain-a so I will be redirect to the url domain-a. I need to stay always inside the domain-b url.

Is there any wordpress configuration that I can do to solve it?

I cannot reproduce the environment because is under a VPN.

Thanks

Comment: Are those two different websites? Or you're just trying to have one website under two domains?